# how to solve error accessing memory address in c eclipse ide?

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, memory, remote-debugging

```
#include "MAIN.h"



#define BILLION  1000000L

timer_t firstTimerID, secondTimerID, thirdTimerID;
double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;

int connectedSocket, acceptSocket;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
struct sockaddr client, dest;
char buf[128];
long rc, sentbytes;
int port = 18017;




void TASK1(Task2ms_Raster)
{

     struct timespec start, stop;
     uint32 StartTime, StopTime;

        if( (StartTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 ) {
          perror("clock gettime");

        }



       // return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 2ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_2msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload2ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 2ms. */
 counter32 += slope32;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 2ms XCP raster. */
  if( enableBypass2ms )
   {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_2msRstr( ) )
        {
     ++numMissingDto2ms;
        }
        }
  if( (StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) {
          perror( "clock gettime" );

        }

  duration2ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
                 + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
                   / (double)BILLION;
        printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration2ms );
}

void TASK2(Task10ms_Raster)
{
     struct timespec start, stop;


            if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_10msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload10ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 10ms. */
    counter16 += slope16;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass10ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_10msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto10ms;
        }
    }

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }
    XCP_FN_TYPE Xcp_CmdProcessor ( );

    duration10ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
                     + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
                       / (double)BILLION;
            printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration10ms );
}


void TASK3(Task100ms_Raster)
{
     struct timespec start, stop;


            if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_100msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload100ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 100ms. */
    counter8 += slope8;


    /* Trigger STIM for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass100ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_100msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto100ms;
        }
    }

    if((clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) {
              perror( "clock gettime" );

            }


    duration100ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
                     + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
                       / (double)BILLION;
            printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration100ms );
}



static void timerHandler( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc )
{
    timer_t *tidp;

    tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

    if ( *tidp == firstTimerID )

        TASK1(Task2ms_Raster);
   else if ( *tidp == secondTimerID )
       TASK2(Task10ms_Raster);
    else if ( *tidp == thirdTimerID )
        TASK3(Task100ms_Raster);
}


 static int makeTimer( char *name, timer_t *timerID, int expireMS, int intervalMS )
{
    struct sigevent         te;
    struct itimerspec       its;
    struct sigaction        sa;
    int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

    /* Set up signal handler. */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
    }

    /* Set and enable alarm */
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
    timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

    return 1;
}



int CreateSocket()
{



       if(rc!=0)

       {

         printf("socket failure code: %ld\n",rc);

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("socket started!\n");

       }

       // Socket creation for UDP

       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)

       {

         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("Socket started!\n");

       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

     addr.sin_port=htons(port);

     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)

     {

       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

       return 1;

     }

     else

     {

       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);

     }




       while(rc!=-1)
       {
         rc= recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf,128,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
           printf("failure: recv, failure code\n");
           break;
         }
         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
            makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
            makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms

     //    buf[rc]='\0';
     //    printf("Client sendet: %s\n",buf);
     //    sprintf(buf2,"Du mich auch %s",buf);
     //    rc=sendto(connectedSocket,buf2,strlen(buf2),0);

       }


       close(acceptSocket);



       return 0;

     }







//
//unsigned __stdcall CheckHandler(void* pArguments)
//{
//  HANDLE h1,h2,h3;
//
//double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;
//
// h1=TimerTask(2,TASK1,&Task2ms_Raster);
// h2=TimerTask(10,TASK2,&Task10ms_Raster);
// h3=TimerTask(100,TASK3,&Task100ms_Raster);
//  _endthreadex( 0 );
// return 0;
//}



int main()
{


     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}




void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{



        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
    }
```

The above is the code for recieving a data from the master via the socket for udp layer. There are some api supported in my project and I created a timer task for calling the task for every 2ms, 10ms and so on. I am debugging this program on the embedded pc target in eclipse ide using remote c/c++ application. when I compile my program there is no error but when i debug my program, it is showing the below errors.

I am recieving error as below:
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Error accessing memory address 0x2b30: Input/output error.

Comment: I don't know about your breakpoint problem, but are you aware that your `BILLION` is defined to be a million?

Comment: what makes the difference ??

Comment: You should really split CreateSocket into CreateSocket and PollSocket.  Can you see the print output?  If you do and you can't set breakpoints, try adding some print statements to find out where it is stopping.

Comment: @user3252048: Um, the number of zeroes? A billion has 9, not 6.